# Module variable can't be initiated with DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, modularity, variable-initialization

I'm trying to keep my Javascript code inside of modules, but I am not being able to initialize the module's variables with DOM elements. Everything I have tried have only returned empty variables.

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myModule.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="baner"></div>

    /* bunch of HTML here */

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        myModule.init();
      });          
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript code looks like this:

#### myModule.js

```
var myModule = (function(){
  var banerSegment;

  var init = function(){
    //Inicializar variáveis relacionadas ao DOM
    banerSegment = $('#baner');
  };

  return {
    init: init,
    baner: banerSegment
  };
})();
```

The way I see it, I thought that after the DOM was ready, the `myModule.init()` function would be called and this function would populate the variable `banerSegment` with the contents of the DOM element. But I only get undefined from calling `myModule.baner`.

Why am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your init function is only setting the variable internally, which is fine when you initialize it for the first time because you are returning the object, but any subsequent calls will not do anything because the variable is local to the IIFE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the article that @mhodges suggested, I figured out I could use a public function to return the private variable. The result looks like this:

```
var myModule = (function(){
  var _banerSegment;

  var init = function(){
    //Inicializar variáveis relacionadas ao DOM
    _banerSegment = $('#baner');
  };
  var returnBaner = function(){
    return _banerSegment;
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    baner: returnBaner
  };
})();
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't mind saying myModule.baner() and calling it as a function, rather than a regular property. I would recommend checking out my edited solution, because it is a bit cleaner, and it allows you to access myModule.baner without invoking it as a function, but honestly either method does the same thing.

Comment: Hey @mhodges! You got it! That's the perfect solution. Now I can even remove the `baner` from the `return` statement! :)

Answer (score 2):

While this is a good start, I don't think you've quite grasped the module pattern yet. I would suggest checking out Todd Motto's guide [here](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)

#### EDIT -- removed less than optimal solution

I think the cleanest solution would be using `this` like so:

```js
var myModule = (function() {
  var init = function() {
    //Inicializar variáveis relacionadas ao DOM
    this.baner = $("#baner");
  };

  return {
    init: init,
    baner: undefined
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  myModule.init();
  console.log(myModule.baner);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#baner"></div>
```

Comment: Hello @mhodges! Thanks for the answer. Well, I have started used (or at least trying) the "modularized" standard especially because I have read the article you mentioned! But the article mention mainly only methods, no examples with variables. But it lead me to one way of achieving what I was looking for! Take a look below.

Comment: @FTM True, he doesn't go into much detail with variables. Although how I came up with the edited solution was from the "Understanding 'return'" section with the `defaults: {name: "Todd"}` example. I kind of just extrapolated and experimented from there